# Как убрать при верстке белый border по краям письма в почтовике Thunderbird?

Tags: html, css, email, thunderbird

При тестировании рассылки сверстанного письма в почтовике Thunderbird по краям основного окна отображается белый border при этом значение padding и Margin у body и оберточной таблицы - ноль. На мобиле все норм. Какие магические тэги и стили могут его убрать? Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Встречаются похожие баги в аутлуке ,и один из вариантов это поиграться с размером шрифта +/- 1 пиксель, проблема в том что не всегда изменение шрифта в блоке где есть эта линия помогает, порой приходиться перелопатить все письм